# Tensorflow 2.0: AttributeError: Tensor.name is meaningless when eager execution is enabled

Tags: tensorflow2.0

Keep getting these errors with tensorflow 2.0. Is this supposed to work?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.constant(3.0)
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    t.watch(x)
    y = (x - 10) ** 2
    opt = tf.optimizers.Adam()
    opt.minimize(lambda: y, var_list=[x])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the tape you only have to compute the forward pass the optimizer and the minize definition are not part of the forward pass, thus you have to remote them.

Moreover, if you want to use the `minimize` method of the optimizer, you don't have to use the `tf.GradienTape` object, but just define the forward pass (loss computation) as a function, then the optimizer will create the tape + minimize the function for you.

However, since you want to use a constant and not a variable, you have to use a `tf.GradientTape` and manually compute the loss value.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(3.0)
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    t.watch(x)
    y = (x - 10) ** 2
grads = t.gradient(y, [x])
```

Of course you **can't** apply the gradients

```py
opt = tf.optimizers.Adam()
opt.apply_gradients(zip([y], [x]))
```

since `x` is not a trainable variable, but a constant (the `apply_gradients` call will raise an exception)

Comment: Thanks, the constant should probably be a variable, was just trying different things to debug.

Comment: The same error occurs if y and x are not the same size lists `opt.apply_gradients(zip([y], [x]))` or if they're the same size but one of the lists contains `None` elements